# Distinguish the nonmember function with the member function in header file

Tags: c++, header-files

> Nonmember functions that are part of the interface of a class should be declared in the same header as the class itself.

The upper quote came from the book C++Primer 5th ed. I wonder if there is a best practice to distinguish nonmember functions and member functions in the header file? Or this is not necessary at all?

Or put it this way: 
As a designer of a class, is it necessary to tell the user in the header file that which function is only part of the interface and which one is member function?

Comment: How do you mean? Members are declared inside the class definition, non-members outside of it. What other kind of distinction did you have in mind?

Comment: @molbdnilo and if they are *defined* outside the class, they require `ClassName::` qualification

Comment: @I mean inside the header file, is there an necessary, for example, to add a comments to distinguish the interface function/member function and the nonmember function

Comment: Comments are *solely* for humans. And when it talks about interface, it doesn't mean the Java keyword `interface`, but all the non-private symbols defined relating to the class

Comment: @Caleth Members do, yes, but the question is about declarations.

Comment: What *I* do is to use snake_case() for non-member functions and camelCase() for member functions.

Comment: The quote does not refer to a distinction between "interface" members (in the Java/abstract base class sense) and other members, it's between on the one hand public members (the class interface) and on the other hand non-members that are considered part of the programming interface (in the general sense, not the Java sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language syntax already distinguishes members from non members, both for definition and declaration.

### Declarations

```
class Example
{
public:
    void member(int); // member, inside the class definition
    friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream &, Example &); // non-member, marked with keyword friend
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, Example &); // non-member, outside the class definition
```

### Definitions

```
void Example::member(int param) {} // Example:: qualification on the name
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, Example &) { return is; } // no Example::
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Example &) { return os; } // no Example::
```

You can often lay the header out in sections, and give the group a heading, but the distinction is apparent from the syntax